# R: optimization for large data in R

Tags: r, optimization, mle

I have a panel data that consists of 5908 individual observations in 5 years.
I want to estimate the maximum likelihood estimator using optim() package.
Here's my code

```
library(pglm)
library(plm)
data("HealthIns")
dat<- pdata.frame(HealthIns,index = c("id","year"))
summary(dat)

dat$claims<-ifelse(dat$size>=4,1,0)
y<-data.matrix(dat$claims)
y[is.na(y)]=0
Y<-matrix(data=y,nrow=5908,ncol=5)

dat$ageclass<-ifelse(dat$age >=30,1,0)
x1<-data.matrix(dat$ageclass)
x1[is.na(x1)]=0
X1<-matrix(data=x1,nrow=5908,ncol=5)

dat$gender <-ifelse(dat$sex=="male",1,0)
x2<-data.matrix(dat$gender)
x2[is.na(x2)]=0
X2<-matrix(data=x2,nrow=5908,ncol=5)

dat$child<-ifelse(dat$child=="yes",1,0)
x3<-data.matrix(dat$child)
x3[is.na(x3)]=0
X3<-matrix(data=x3,nrow=5908,ncol=5)
```

The -log likelihood that I want to use is

```
po.gam=function(para){
  #Lambda(i,t)
  {for (i in (1:5908)){
    for(t in (1:5)){
    lambda<-as.matrix(exp(para[1] + para[2]*X1 + para[3]*X2 + para[4]*X3),nrow=5908,ncol=5)}}
  }
  
 
  num.claims.of.t <-numeric(nrow(Y))
  {for (i in seq(nrow(Y))){
    num.claims.of.t[i] <-sum(Y[i,])}
  }
  
  num.lambda.of.t<-numeric(nrow(Y))
  {for (i in seq(nrow(Y))){
    num.lambda.of.t[i]<-sum(lambda[i,])}
  }
  
  prod.exp<-numeric(nrow(Y))
  {for (i in seq(nrow(Y))){
    prod.exp[i]<-prod(lambda[i,]^Y[i,]/factorial(Y[i,]))}
  }
  
  
  joint.pdf.mvnb<-(prod.exp)*(gamma(num.claims.of.t + (1/para[5]))/gamma(1/para[5]))*(((1/para[5])/(num.lambda.of.t + (1/para[5])))^(1/para[5]))*((num.lambda.of.t + (1/para[5]))^(-num.claims.of.t))
  
  #PRODUC NUMBER OF CLAIMS SEMUA INDIVIDU
  prod.mvnb=1
  for (i in (length(joint.pdf.mvnb))){
    prod.mvnb<-prod(joint.pdf.mvnb[i])
  }
  return(-log(prod.mvnb))
}
```

Then using optim()

```
start.value <- c(beta0=0.01,beta1=0.01,beta2=0.01,beta3=0.01,alfa=0.01)
MLE_pogam<-optim(start.value,fn=po.gam,hessian=FALSE)
MLE_pogam
```

And the program will run more than 2 hours still without any output.
Do you have any suggestion for optimize the log likelihood function for the big data?
Thank you!!

Comment: I didn't go into the details, but perhaps you need to look for a more optimized function to perform this. From the documentation of optim `The default method is an implementation of that of Nelder and Mead (1965), that uses only function values and is robust but relatively slow. `.

Comment: The first four lines of the function calculate lambda 5908*5 times, but it is independent of `i` and `t`, so the result will be exactly the same each time, so the for loops could be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `pso` package. It implements the [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) algorithm with `pso::psoptim()` as a direct replacement for the `optim()` function. It is a stochastic algorithm, so it should be relatively faster.

Comment: Hi! I have tried your solution, but it turns out 
"Error in if (f.x[i] < f.p[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE need"
do you have any suggestions to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't try your example out yet, but this error seems to be an internal error in the `psoptim` function! Maybe you're not passing the arguments in the proper way. For example, the cost function needs to return a scalar. Please take a look at the docs https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pso/versions/1.0.3/topics/psoptim. I hope that helps!